# GridView AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox that is disabled when a dropdownlist is set to one value (**A**) and enabled when it's set to another (**B**). While in Edit Mode, if the textbox is **disabled (dropdownlist value is A)** and the value of the of the dropdownlist is changed to **B**, how can I get the textbox to become enabled?

ASP .NET code that disables textbox:

```
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GRP") %>' MaxLength = "10" 
                    Enabled = '<%# !Eval("GRP_NM").ToString().Equals("A") %>' Height="19px" 
                    Width="70px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register dropdownlist `SelectedIndexChanged` event and in handler perform the enabling/disabling of textbox.